# Modificar URL register en Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy creando un proyecto en Laravel 5.8, y quiero reutilizar la url register que viene por defecto, sin embargo, necesito que esta url contenga /admin/ . Ejemplo

**Por defecto viene:**

```
 /register
```

**Se quiere que sea:**

```
 /admin/register
```

Ya que solo los usuarios con rol administrador, podrán crear registros. Mi archivo de ruta web.php es:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {

    Route::get('/admin/usuarios', 'UserController@index');
    //aca rutas para /admin/register

});
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estás definiendo la ruta?

Comment: acabo de editar la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asumiendo que utilizas la función `Auth::routes();` en tu routes/web.php, debes modificarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
// No utilizar las rutas para registro que están incluidas
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);

// Redefinimos las rutas de registro con el prefijo deseado
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
});
```

Para más información:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-group-prefixes
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1143

---

Para aplicar un middleware, puede hacerse de esta forma:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
});
```

Comment: A ese código como le puedo poner el middleware de admin, ya que me funciona, pero el usuario que no es admin puede entrar a /admin/register

Comment: Ok Gracias!! ahi funciona